# Is rolling actually faster?

Tags: psychonauts

When I use levitation and run on my psychic ball I feel like I'm moving faster is this actually the case or is it a sort of illusion?

I know I sacrifice maneuverability so it'd make sense that I'm also faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the levitation ball allows you to move faster on the ground. The levitation ball can also help you climb faster. See the [compiled list](http://kb.speeddemosarchive.com/Psychonauts) of Psychonauts speedrunning tips.

Comment: I don’t see moving with the levitation ball discussed at all on that SDA page. Though maybe that technique is too basic and they assume everyone knows it’s faster. Anyway, I’ve noticed that at the very least, using the levitation ball to roll downhill is faster than walking. Flat surfaces and uphill I’m not sure about.